# Rotation span of SparkFun ROB-09065 servo

Tags: servo, remote-control, robotics

Does anybody know what the rotational span of the [ROB-09065 servo](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9065) from SparkFun?

And even better, is there a datasheet available anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They claim that it's similar to the HS-55, which has a 180 degree span.

http://www.servocity.com/html/hs-55_sub-micro.html

Comment: In reality it is more like 170 degrees.